# travel insurance only for missed or canceled flights

Tags: air-travel, insurance, indonesia, cancellations, missed-flights

I am traveling to Indonesia the next month and I am told that flights are often delayed or canceled. Therefore one can easily miss a connection or miss the first (already paid) night in some hotel.

I already have a medical insurance for when traveling and I am even insured for lost luggage. The only thing I am missing is an insurance that covers flights issues. Is there such an insurance? Can you recommend any?